# ArrayList, Loop and requisite if can not work that i want - Java 11

Tags: java, list, loops, if-statement, arraylist

I have a problem comparing the numbers inside a list so that it does not repeat using Random. I wanted the numbers to be random, but only those that are not on the list can be added.

Here is my code:

```
private void addToListNumber() {

int randomPosition = new Random().nextInt(5);
int maxPosition = 5;

        if (list.size() < 1) {
            list.add(1);
            addToListNumber();
        } else if (list.size() < maxPosition) {
            for (Integer integer : list) {
                if (integer == randomPosition) {
                    addToListNumber();
                }
            }
            list.add(randomPosition);
            addToListNumber();
        } else {

            for (Integer integer : list) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
        }
    }
```

The numbers are repeated.

Comment: I don't see any code here that attempts to prevent duplicate numbers. It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you're trying to build a list of 5 integers, in a random order.

A simple way to get there is to generate a list of **ordered** numbers and then randomly swap them.

First create your list of ordered numbers.

```java
public List<Integer> createOrderedList(int size) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Then create a method that swaps two elements in the list, given their indexes.

```java
public void swap(List<Integer> list, int i, int j) {
    Integer hold = list.get(i);
    list.set(i, list.get(j));
    list.set(j, hold);
}
```

Last, create a method that mixes all of them.

```java
public void mix(List<Integer> list) {
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        swap(list, i, random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

Call the methods in this order:

```java
List<Integer> list = createOrderedList(5);
mix(list);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the recursive call addToListNumber(). To make it simple and short let me assume maxPosition = 3
At first you add 1 to the list. Then suppose randomPosition = 2 and you add 2 to the list and call addToListNumber(). Now suppose randomPosition = 1, then you call addToListNumber() again on comparing integer == randomPosition (you have compared only the first element here and it matched)

Now let randomPosition = 3 and 3 be inserted. Since, this is a recursive call, on returning to addToListNumber() which was invoked for randomPosition = 1 (in the previous case), the list is not over (the list has {1,2,3}) here and only the first element has been compared. At the end of the loop it inserts 1 again and your list becomes {1,2,3,1} hence duplicates.

Comment: ok thanks, I fixed my code. I use boolean and it work

Here is my fixed
```
if (list.size() < maxPosition) {
            for (Integer integer : list) {
                if (integer == randomPosition) {
                    effect = false;
                }
            }

            if (effect == false) {
                addToListNumber();
            } else {
                list.add(randomPosition);
                addToListNumber();
```